# Specify average of grades in cv

Tags: cv, grades

I studied in Italy and I'm writing a CV for CERN and I would like to specify the average of my grades.

How can I do that? I provide you an example. I had an average of 30.5 out of 30 (honour degrees are counted as 31).

Should I write:

Average grade: 30.5 out of 31

Average grade: 30.5 out of 30 (My university says this)

Should I use GPA? But this is American I think, CERN is in Europe.

Answer (score 21):

My advice, as an Italian, is to avoid any personal interpretation of the grades and get from your university the [Diploma Supplement](https://education.ec.europa.eu/education-levels/higher-education/inclusive-and-connected-higher-education/diploma-supplement), which provides complete information on the grading system. This kind of Supplement has been conceived exactly to allow universities in different countries to better understand their different grading systems, and those I had seen were fairly detailed. It should also provide information on the honours system in use at your university.

If you further want to provide separately your average grade, assuming that it’s not already in the Supplement, I suggest you to use the average grade reported by the university, possibly attaching the source of that value (if your university says so, it should be written somewhere).

Comment: Good advice everywhere, not just Italy.

Comment: Thank you! Diploma supplement is released when the degree is completed. I applied for an internship and I followed your advice, and I used the average grade reported by the university.